# does it required to have individual server SSL certificate for each embedded device?

Tags: security, ssl, embedded, browser, certificate

I have an embedded device which runs a web server.I need to integrate the server SSL certificate for the web server. If I have multiple such boxes, is it required to have different SSL for each box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy a wildcard certificate say for `*.mydevices.mydomain.com`, then give each device a name like `myRouter1.mydevices.mydomain.com` and that's it. Certificate Authorities do sell wildcard certificates, yet they are more expensive (but if you have many devices, this will be cheaper).

You need to consider one thing though - if the certificate's private key leaks from the device in any way (eg. the device is stolen altogether), you can revoke the certificate. But if you have one certificate shared on all devices, then the leak will invalidate all devices at the same time and you will have to replace the no more valid certificate on all devices.

Comment: Can I generate private key for each device and use the wildcard SSL certificate so that each device has a unique private key as if it has separate cert?

Comment: @crusader Different keys means difference certificates. You have two contradictory aspects between which you need to find a balance: ease of management and security. Security requires many certificates and keys. Ease of management requires as few certificates as possible. You choose :).

Comment: I've come across sslshopper.com which states the following line .. "However, some certificate providers allow you to create as many new wildcard certificates (using the same domain name) as needed for all of your servers, each with a unique private key" is n't it what I've been looking for?

Comment: @crusader This is possible but what would you gain? You will still have many certificates to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you're going to get an "it depends":

- If your users require a CA-signed certificate, then you'll have to pay for one for each box and load it some way.  Browser's then won't complain...
- If your users will allow a self-signed certificate, then you can just have the box generate one when it is commissioned.  But, your user's browser's will complain...
- If you ship with the same certificate, then it's kind of a security problem for you.

I would build a mechanism in so the user can load a certificate to the box in the field.  Then you can satisfy whatever need comes up.

Comment: thank you daveoman.I was just thinking the same.this confirms what I was thinking.

Comment: one more Q related to SSL, please confirm my thought.                    does the box need any certificate store? I don't think it is required as the server does have only one certificate for its life. And on the other hand does client(box sometimes has to be,and visit a single website over it's lifetime) require certificate store? again no!, because it has to visit just a single website.

Comment: Some one down-voted, I was going to up-vote, but then.  How does uploading a certificate help?  You could upload in a 'secure mode' only, for instance a serial port.  Then each client browser that contacts the server needs the exception.  This solution *passes the buck* to the user, but also it seems like it maybe insecure depending on *how it is implemented*.  Certainly you don't want anyone to upload a new certificate at any time.

Comment: Yes, the thinking would be to load the cert locally in some way.  That's what I meant by "commissioned"...prior to it being connected for good.  Definitely wouldn't want to allow upload at any time.  As far as passing the buck, if that was an option for the product, then I would think it's just fine.  How many times have you dismissed the cert prompt when browsing?